# Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset -1

Tags: php, upgrade, warnings

I recently upgraded my dedicated server to Apache 2.4.6, MySQL 5.5.32, and PHP 5.4.21. Now on my website I get this error:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset -1 in /home/champion/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 295

Here is the code from shortcodes.php on line 295:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[\x{00a0}\x{200b}]+/u", " ", $text);
```

Is the preg_replace function not compatible with the new PHP 5.4.21?

Comment: Please clarify how this question is *specific to WordPress*.

Comment: It's a WordPress website.

Comment: That doesn't make the question *specific* to WordPress. Per the WPSE FAQ, questions not specific to WordPress are off-topic, *even if they happen in the **context** of WordPress*.

Comment: OK, here's the link to the new thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979832/warning-preg-replace-compilation-failed-unknown-option-bits-set-at-offset)